# Derivative is the rate of change at that point or points near it?

Tags: calculus

The derivative is referred to as the instantaneous rate of change at a point. To clarify, it is only the case that the derivative gives a sort of approximation of what points close to this will have as their slope to this point, right? and that the closer one gets to this point, the closer the slope gets to this?
What is the reasoning behind deeming the derivative the "Instantaneous" rate of change, if the change it refers to is not 'instant' and instead occurs over an interval (albeit small?)
thanks

Comment: *What is the reasoning behind deeming the derivative the 'Instantaneous' rate of change, if the change it refers to is not 'instant' and instead occurs over an interval?* $\quad$ The derivative does belong to that particular instant, not to any interval around it. If what you are today is heavily influenced/shaped by your past and current relationships, that particular property of yours is solely yours rather than shared by those people who have contributed to moulding that property.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can get better clarity on this if we take a look at the definition of a derivative. As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative, "A function of a real variable f(x) is differentiable at a *point a* of its domain, if its domain contains an open interval I containing a, and the limit

> $L = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$

exists. . ."
And the above definition further goes on to say that, "*if the limit L exists, then this limit is called the derivative of f at a*". Therefore, by definition derivatives are indeed referring to the value of the limit (slope) at a particular point (instant).

Now the question comes as to why are we dealing with limits here ? Why not just say that, at this particular point the value of the slope (limit) is $x$.

This is because, derivative is a function defined on the real number line. And by definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number)
"*real number can be almost uniquely represented by an infinite decimal expansion*". Which, points to the fact that the limit can be accurately found to the $n^{th}$ decimal, but since the decimal expansion is infinite, there is always scope for being even more accurate. And in order to accommodate this fact we define derivatives at $\lim_{x\to y}$, rather than $x = y$.